# can we disable the buffering in Youtube video playing using API in Android?

Tags: android, performance, youtube-api

public class VideoDialog extends YouTubeFailureRecoveryActivity  {

```
    List<String> playlist;
    AlertDialog dialog;
    YouTubePlayer player;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        playlist=new ArrayList<String>();
        playlist=bundle.getStringArrayList("VIDEO_LINK");
        if(!playlist.isEmpty())
        {

            dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exvideo_lauout, null); // xml Layout file for imageView

            Button btnCloseimg=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.eximageclose);
            btnCloseimg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(player.isPlaying())
                    {
                        player.release();
                    }
                    playlist.clear();
                    playlist=null;
                    finish();




                }
            });

            YouTubePlayerView youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView)view. findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
            youTubeView.initialize(DEVELOPER_KEY,this);



            dialog.setView(view);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            lp.copyFrom(dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
            lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT-150;
            dialog.show();
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Error in URL..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();


    }

    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if(player.isPlaying())
        {
            player.release();
        }
        playlist.clear();
        playlist=null;
        finish();

    }

    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer player,boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) 
        {

            this.player=player;
            player.loadVideos(playlist);
            player.setPlayerStyle(PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);

            player.play();


            player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(new PlayerStateChangeListener() {

                public void onVideoStarted() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onVideoEnded() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    if(!player.hasNext())
                    {
                        //player.cueVideos(playlist);
                        player.loadVideos(playlist);
                        player.play();

                    }
                    else
                    {

                        player.play();
                    }


                }

                public void onLoading() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(VideoDialog.this,"Loading Error!!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                public void onAdStarted() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                }
            });

        }
    }


    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }



}
```

> we need to play multiple videos inside an android app without any delay,but initial loading time is high in         youtube Player APi.is there any way to reduce video quality depend on device???

Comment: Doesn't seem to be according to the documentation... did you try calling `play()` in the overriden `onLoading()` method?

Answer (score -1):

Wait I found something in the docs provided with the API. Look in

```
/docs/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener.html#onBuffering(boolean)
```

or just `YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener.html#onBuffering(boolean)`

It seems to have the callback that you need to override.

Seems like there's a `PlayBackEventListener` which provides you with the `onBuffering` you're looking for.

Comment: the onbuffering not contain the good information and it called only when the state change ! onBuffering is call with false one time when the video is already in buffering... I don't find the good way